# Zend Framework 2 Mail SmtpOptions SSL

Tags: email, ssl, zend-framework2, smtp

I'm trying to figure out how I could send email using Zend SMTP Transport and SSL. The new SmtpOptions class doesn't seem to include the property for the ssl. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of passing SSL options to the `SmtpOptions` class:

```
use Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp as SmtpTransport;
use Zend\Mail\Transport\SmtpOptions;

// Setup SMTP transport using LOGIN authentication
$transport = new SmtpTransport();
$options   = new SmtpOptions(array(
    'name'              => 'localhost.localdomain',
    'host'              => '127.0.0.1',
    'connection_class'  => 'login',
    'connection_config' => array(
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'pass',
        'ssl'      => 'tls', // can use tls or ssl
    ),
));
$transport->setOptions($options);
$transport->send($message);
```

Hope that helps.